# package up objects to pass to a method

Tags: c#

In a project, there are several instances of goat objects that get created as follows:

```
Goat nubian = GetProductionStatistics(nubian);
Goat alpine = GetProductionStatistics(alpine);
Goat saanen = GetProductionStatistics(saanen);
```

Once created, these get passed to another method like so:

```
CalculateProductionPotential(nubian, alpine, saanen);
```

Given that more breeds of goats will be added in the future, I'd like to "package up" the goat objects into a single thing, let's call it `allGoats`, that can be passed to the method that takes it as an argument: `CalculateProductionPotential(allGoats)`.  This will eliminate modifying the method signature each time.  How can this be achieved?

Comment: Creating a `List<Goat>`, add elements to this list and pass it?

Comment: What you're describing is a collection. Like, exactly it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is confusing because you are passing the goat object to a factory that creates it. Assuming you really mean to pass a string or something...here's how to do this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var goats = new List<Goat>
        {
            {GetProductionStatistics("nubian") },
            {GetProductionStatistics("alpine") },
            {GetProductionStatistics("saanen") } 
        };

        CalculateProductionPotential(goats);
    }

    private static void CalculateProductionPotential(List<Goat> goats)
    {
        foreach (var goat in goats)
        {
            // Process here
        }

    }

    private static Goat GetProductionStatistics(string type)
    {
        var goat = new Goat(); 

        // Some processing... 
        return goat; 
    }
}
```

Comment: In `CalculateProductionPotential` there is logic specific to the nubian breed.  How can the list item that pertains to nubians be isolated to apply that logic?

Comment: Your Goat class should have a property indicating the type of goat. So if (goat.Type == "Nubian") ... in the real world you would probably have an enum not a string for this but this illustrates the idea.